# Calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) weirdness

Tags: java, calendar, week-number

Either I don't understand the method `getActualMaximum(int)` or the field WEEK_OF_YEAR, or there's a Sun bug involved (or all three)...could someone explain to me why (at least **in a German locale**...) the following code:

```
    Locale.setDefault( Locale.GERMAN );
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set( Calendar.YEAR, 2010 );
    c.set( Calendar.MONTH, 0 );
    c.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
    System.out.println("max:    "+c.getActualMaximum( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ));
    System.out.println("actual: "+c.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ));
```

produces the following output:

```
    max:    52
    actual: 53
```

Here's the Javadoc of `getActualMaximum(int)`:

> Returns the maximum value that the
>   specified calendar field could have,
>   given the time value of this Calendar.
>   For example, the actual maximum value
>   of the MONTH field is 12 in some
>   years, and 13 in other years in the
>   Hebrew calendar system.

---

***Edit***

The plot thickens. **In an English locale** (`-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=us`) the output is:

```
    max:    52
    actual: 1
```

Seems to point to it being a Sun bug for German locales?

Comment: days start at 1, but months start at zero?

Comment: uh yeah. believe it or not. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is correct:

```
max:    52
actual: 53
```

The year 2010 has a maximum of 52 weeks. The actual week is 53, since 2009 has maximum 53 weeks and most weeks start on sunday or monday. Week 1 is in most cases the first week of the year with 4 days in january. Since the week of the january 1st has only 2 or 3 days in 2010, the week is considered part of 2009.

Most likely the english locale has different rules for determing week 1, like the first week is the week of january 1st.

Wikipedia explains it correctly: [wikipedia week article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering)

Comment: Thanks...but as far as I read the Javadoc, it seems that getActualMaximum doesn't give me the maximum for the year, but rather for the time value of the calendar: so shouldn't that give me an actual maximum of 53 for January 1st?

Comment: depends on what is considered the actual time. the year 2010 has 52 weeks, 2009 has 53 weeks. you should take a look at the source code for the actual implementation

Comment: yeah that's what I've ended up doing...after looking at the source code, I've basically come up with a workaround: to get the TRUE actual maximum of a year, get the calendar week of december 31. if this is 1, then the actual maximum for that year is 52. so frickin' complicated... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that January 1st 2010 is in week 53 of 2009 (in Germany), but year 2010 only has 52 weeks (December 31st 2010 is in week 52). The Java Calendar object unfortunately does not have a field for the year, to which the week number relates.