# calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) returns 52 for months 1-11 and returns 53 for month 12

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am using calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) to get total number of weeks in a given year. This is the function I am using :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i=2012; i<=2016; i++) {
        System.out.println("Year : " + i + ", Total Weeks : " + getNumWeeksForYear(i));
    }

}
public static int getNumWeeksForYear(int year) {  
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();           
    c.set(year, 12, 31); //issue
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY );
    return c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);   
}
```

```
Output with c.set(year, 12, 31): 
Year : 2012, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2013, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2014, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2015, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2016, Total Weeks : 53
```

```
Output with c.set(year, 1, 31): 
Year : 2012, Total Weeks : 53
Year : 2013, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2014, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2015, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2016, Total Weeks : 52
```

I am unable to figure it out why the total weeks in a year are different when the calendar month is set to Dec. I have tried using months 1-12, for 1-11 the number of weeks are same but changes for the month 12. From the experiment I can predict it only happens with leap years.

I had referred the following link: [Calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047673/calendar-getactualmaximumcalendar-week-of-year-weirdness)

But this does not answer my query.

Answer (score 2):

The first month is

```
private static final int JANUARY = 0;
```

and the last month is

```
private static final int DECEMBER = 11;
```

This means that month `12` is the first month of the next year.

Comment: @Peter : Thanks. You are correct. But if I use 11(Dec of current month 2016), it returns 52 weeks whereas 2016 has 53 weeks. What is the correct way to get the total number of weeks?

Answer (score 1):

Here months index starts form 0  like this.

```
JANUARY=0, FEBRUARY=1,.., DECEMBER=11
```

So till 11 it will return correct values

Example code:

```
public static int getNumWeeksForYear(int year) {  
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();           
        c.set(year, 11,31); //issue
        c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY );
        return c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);   
    }
```

output:

```
Year : 2012, Total Weeks : 53
Year : 2013, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2014, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2015, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2016, Total Weeks : 52
```

If you give grater than 11

```
c.set(year, 14,31);
```

output:

```
Year : 2012, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2013, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2014, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2015, Total Weeks : 52
Year : 2016, Total Weeks : 53
```

to calculate accurate weeks in a year [see this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27133400/2670061)